# MS Access mporting dates

Tags: date, ms-access

At the end of importing a .txt file through the help of the wizard i get a message that some elements were not imported correctly. I have a column in the .txt which should contain dates, but for some reason when i select the column containing dates, and i set its type to date and time, for some reason access cannot recognize them as dates. I'm thinking that it's because of the language difference. I use dates like: 1.1.2011, whereas access uses 1/1/2011.

Where can i change the format?

Answer (score 1):

You can in the *Advanced* section of the *Import Wizard*.

If that doesn't work, don't import but link the file and specify the date field as text.

Then create a simple select query where you use the linked table as source. Select all the fields you need.

For the date field, use this expression:

```
TrueDate: CDate(Replace([YourTextDateField], ".", "/"))
```

Clean up other fields as well.

Now use this query for the further processing of the data.